# Invariance of the Möbius function under order isomorphism

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, mobius-function

Let $(X,\leq)$ and $(Y,\leq)$ be locally finite partially ordered sets
with Möbius functions $\mu_X$ respectively $\mu_Y$,
and let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be an order isomorphism.
I want to show that
\begin{equation*}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x_2)) = \mu_X(x_1,x_2)
\end{equation*}
for all $x_1,x_2\in X$, $x_1\leq x_2$.

In e.g. Carl G. Wagner's book,
A First Course in Enumerative Combinatorics, p. 235,
I find a proof that use's Philip Hall's theorem.
I am not familiar with this theorem,
but it appears to rely on the chain structure of posets.
Instead of diving into this approach,
I was wondering if the following approach is correct.

By definition,
the Möbius function is the inverse of the zeta function
with respect to convolution on the
[incidence algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra),
i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{x_1\leq x_\leq x_2}
\mu(x_1,x)\zeta(x,x_2)
=
(\mu * \zeta)(x_1,x_2)
=
\delta(x_1,x_2)
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\delta(x_1,x_2)
=
\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1&\text{if }x_1=x_2,
\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
is the multiplicative unit in the incidence algebra,
and $\zeta(x_1,x_2) = 1$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$, $x_1\leq x_2$.

Using subscripts $X$ and $Y$ to refer to the specific posets $X$ and $Y$,
I now argue that by convoluting $\mu_Y(\varphi(\cdot),\varphi(\cdot))$ with $\delta_X$,
then using the identity $\delta_X = \zeta_X * \mu_X$,
followed by associativity of convolution
and the fact that $\zeta_X = \zeta_Y(\varphi(\cdot),\varphi(\cdot))$,
will yield the desired identity.
That is, for any $x_1,x_2\in X$, $x_1\leq x_2$, we have
\begin{aligned}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x_2))
&=
(\mu_Y(\varphi(\cdot),\varphi(\cdot)) * \delta_X)(x_1,x_2)
\\
&=
\sum_{x_1\leq x\leq x_2}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x))\delta_X(x,x_2)
\\
&=
\sum_{x_1\leq x\leq x_2}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x))(\zeta_X * \mu_X)(x,x_2)
\\
&=
\sum_{x_1\leq x\leq y\leq x_2}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x))
\zeta_X(x,y)
\mu_X(y,x_2)
\\
&=
\sum_{x_1\leq x\leq y\leq x_2}
\mu_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x))
\zeta_Y(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))
\mu_X(y,x_2)
\\
&=
\sum_{x_1\leq y\leq x_2}
\delta_Y(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(y))
\mu_X(y,x_2)
\\
&=
\mu_X(x_1,x_2)
\end{aligned}
Is this a valid proof of the above statement?

Comment: I am pretty sure that your proof is correct. Every step appears rigorous, and it makes intuitive sense; since $\phi$ trivially preserves the $\delta$ and $\zeta$ functions, and the $\mu$ is determined by them, it must preserve $\mu$ as well. I am not comfortable enough in this subject to give an authoritative answer, so I thought I should just leave this comment.